# Is the creating nonclustered PK syntax inconsistent?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, primary-key, non-clustered-index

SQL Server 2008 R2

Why

```
create table A
(
   id int,
   primary key nonclustered (id)
)
```

is correct and executed without errors?

But

```
create table A
(
   id int,
   primary key nonclustered id
)
```

is an error? giving

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

<strike>Collateral question:

Why</strike>

```
create table c(id int primary key clustered)
```

is executed
but

```
create table c(id int primary key nonclustered)
```

is an error? Sorry, both work.

Is it inconsistent syntax to be suggested for correction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The (id) should be in parenthesis. Like CHECK conditions and FOREIGN KEY columns. On one line:

```
create table A (id int, primary key nonclustered (id)) --ok
create table A (id int, primary key nonclustered id) --not ok
```

Note: the comma implies "table level constraint". The other syntax *without* the comma means "column level constraint". Of course PKs are per table, you can have composite keys which can't be defined at the column level:

```
create table A (
   id int,
   something datetime,

   primary key clustered (id,something)
)
```

Note: I'd always be explicit about my constraints too for names. Otherwise SQL Server generate a hex looking one. As well as explicitly defining nullability and index style. So I'd write this:

```
create table A (
   id int NOT NULL,
   something datetime NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT PK_A PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id,something)
)
```

Finally, according to [CREATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx), this is OK and works on my SQL Server 2008 instance:

```
 create table c(id int primary key nonclustered)
```

Comment: +1, thanks, but I could not quite understand about syntax without comma. The question was rather about syntax with(out) excessive parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses are essential because otherwise there would be no way to delimit the PRIMARY KEY column list from whatever follows it (which could be a column or another constraint).